# Typescript create typeguard with errors

Tags: typescript, typeguards

```
type LoggedContext = Required<ApolloContext>;
function authMiddleware(context: ApolloContext): context is LoggedContext {
  if (!context.user) {
    throw new AuthenticationError("Resolver requires login");
  }

  return true;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
async user(_, { id }, context) {
    authMiddleware(context);

    const user = context.user;
    // expect typescript to infer that user is defined and not null
  },
```

Is there some way to help typescript infer the correct type? I.e. to know that if the code after the middleware executes, it is "logged"?

Basically, the goal is to not have to put the authMiddleware(context) in an if check.

Comment: If `authMiddleware` is a type guard, why not do `if (authMiddleware(context)) { const user = context.user }`?

Comment: @KarolMajewski First thing that comes to mind is you don't usually have just one middleware but at least a few, which creates multiple nested ifs and not very good readability. I'm sure there could be other good reasons as development furthers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something like a [type assertion at block-scope level](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10421), which is not a TypeScript feature (as of 3.3).  You might want to go to that GitHub issue and give it a  or describe your use case if it is particularly compelling and hasn't already been mentioned.  So for now there's no way to use a type guard to unequivocally narrow the type of a variable without doing an `if` check.

What can you do instead?  What I usually do in cases like this is to replace the type guard with a function which returns the narrowed object, so instead of `x is T`, just return `T`:

```
function authMiddleware(context: ApolloContext): LoggedContext {
  if (!context.user) {
    throw new AuthenticationError("Resolver requires login");
  }
  // the following assertion is equivalent to the type guard returning true
  return context as LoggedContext;
}
```

Now when you use this function, use the returned value instead of the original parameter for all subsequent references:

```
const aContext = authMiddleware(context);
// use aContext instead of context from now on:

const user = aContext.user; // string
```

Maybe that will help you or give you some ideas on how to proceed.  Good luck!